# Parameterizing an XML drawable

Tags: android, layout, android-drawable, statelistdrawable

I want to create a family of buttons. They all look the same, except for their color. The brute force way of doing this would be to copy/paste the layout into N files, then change the colors in each one.

What’s the more elegant way of achieving this? In the sample code below, I'd like to use different colors instead of `@color/round_green_button_pressed_background` and `@color/round_green_button_unpressed_background`, but everything else should ideally stay in one place.

Doing this programmatically seems even worse than copy/pasting the files, so hopefully, there’s an answer that involves pure XML-based layouts.

Sample code: `button_green.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
      <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
      <solid android:color="@color/round_green_button_pressed_background"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape>
      <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
      <solid android:color="@color/round_green_button_unpressed_background"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Making several xml ressources would be the solution.. How many buttons do you need ?

Comment: use Drawable.setColorFilter()

Comment: So, no way to do this in markup alone? (Both replies so far refer either to code or copy/paste.)